# Loop asp repeater items using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Can anyone help on how to loop items in repeater using Jquery. I have this code

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptData">
  <HeaderTemplate>
    <div style="border: 1px solid #c4c4c4; width: 98%; font:8px;">
        <table cellpadding="4px" id="tbValue" width="100%" style="margin:0;">
            <tr>
                <td width="30%" style="background-color: #CCC;">Qty</td>
                <td width="60%" style="background-color: #CCC;">Description</td>
                <td width="60%" style="background-color: #CCC;">ID</td>
            </tr>
  </HeaderTemplate>
  <ItemTemplate>
    <tr style="background: #fff" <%# If(Container.ItemIndex Mod 2=0 , "class='odd'", "") %>>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtQuantity" runat="server" CssClass="textbox" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="lblDesc" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Description")%>' CssClass="LabelInfo" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="lblId" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Kit_ID")%>' />
        </td>
    </tr>
  </ItemTemplate>
  <FooterTemplate>
    </table>
    </div>
  </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" CssClass="button" Width="150px" style="margin: 1.5em 2em 0 0;" />
```

What I’m trying to do is, In button click I want to get each txtqty in repeater and check if the value is equal to 10. If equal to 10 – i will get the value of lbldesc, if less than 10 i will get the lblId value

The output should be 
-Equal tom 10

```
DESCRIPTION    - QUANTITY
Itemxxx        – 10 
Itemwww        – 10 

ID - QUANTITY
1  – 7 
2  – 2
```

Comment: This is not how you're supposed to ask on SO. Small remark though, you'll get better help showing the rendered HTML than your .NET code, as the javascript will loop on HTML elements...

Answer (score 2):

First of all you cannot access the fields directly using the id like `#lbldesc` in jquery when using repeater, because asp assigns its own unique values to every field that is generated by the repeater.

That said, you still have an option to get the data and use it, using css classes here is how you can achieve this:

Assign the classes to both `lbldesc` and `lblId`: lets say the same class is given, now you can easily loop through them in jquery like this:

```
$('#btnSubmit').click(function(){
     var equalToTen = new Array();
        var notEqualToTen = new Array();

        $('.textbox').each(function () {
            if (Number($(this).val()) > 10) {
                equalToTen.push($(this).closest('tr').find('.lbldesc').html());
            }
            else {
                notEqualToTen.push($(this).closest('tr').find('.lblId').html());
            }
        });

        for (var i = 0; i < equalToTen.length; i++) {
            alert("I am equal to 10: " + equalToTen.pop());
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < notEqualToTen.length; i++) {
            alert("I am not equal to 10: " + notEqualToTen.pop());
        }
});
```

**NOTE:** Arrays and loops are only for example.
Hope this answers your question

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#btn').on('click',function(){
  $('#txtQuantity').each(function () 
   {
      var val;
      if($(this).val()==10)
      {
        val=$(this).closest('tr').find('#lblDesc').text();
      }
      else
      {
        val=$(this).closest('tr').find('#lblId').text();
      }
   });

 });
```

This is a simple Jquery code which would the job for you.

**EDIT:
The above code has been edited**

Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

could be like this

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$(buttonselector).on('click',function(){ 
  $('.textbox').each(function(){
      if($(this).val() == 10){
         $(outputselector).html($(this).next('#lbldesc').html());
      }
      else{
       $(outputselector).html($(this).next('#lblId').html());
      }
  });

})
});
</script>
```

where as those #net controllers make this ugly id's though better give lbldesc and  lblId an css class and use the css class as an selector

Comment: is it possible to include lbldesc or lblid inside each.function - actually i will not add the value, all i need to is to check if value is 10 or not.